# vim :make automatically jumps to first file with error

Tags: vim

When executing :make from vim, after make is complete it automatically jumps to a file with errors. Is there a way to avoid this

**EDIT**

This is usecase i want to achieve
I want :make to execute then quicklist to open but the current file which i am working on should not be switched to the one with errors

with default settings after :make execution quicklist opens and the current file also changes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run `:make! | copen`, which should place your cursor in the quickfix list instead of changing the current buffer.  You can make this even easier by putting `command Mymake make! | copen` in your .vimrc, so you only have to run `:Mymake` to do this.

Note that when selecting errors from the quickfix list, they will scroll a buffer with the file already open rather than change the current window if possible, and you can open the files in new windows with `<C-w> Enter`.

Comment: I'm surprised this was accepted - while of course `copen` by definition activates the list of errors, if `:make!` changed the open file, it'll still have changed.

Comment: @Jefromi I don't know what you mean. Your own answer says that `:make!` does _not_ change the open file.

Answer (score 22):

From the docs:

```
    7. If [!] is not given the first error is jumped to.
```

So, just invoke it as `:make!`.

Comment: even with this option it jumped to the file.

Comment: I've just tested on vim 7.1 using `:make!` did not jump to the first error, I was still on the same spot in the file where I open it - error was in different file

Comment: Is there some way to configure it to reverse the normal behaviour? So :make does what :make! normally does and vice-versa? Ideally across various quickfix functions like :grep, :Ack, :Ag.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the cleanest solution, but setting the errorformat to an empty string should do the trick, ie.

```
:set errorformat=""
```

That should keep it from matching the compiler error strings.

Comment: This gives me the error message "E378: 'errorformat' contains no pattern". However, setting it to something that doesn't match (I used "!" as a quick test now) seems to work.